# Dynamic change the max of a form field based on a selected item of the form (CS50 PSET8 Finances)

Tags: javascript, forms, cs50

I have a form that the options for a dropdown menu are fed to it from a list of dicts. Each dict has a ["symbol"] and a ["shares"] item. The dropdown options are looped through with a for loop.

I am trying to make it so when I select an option from my dropdown menu, the maximum imput of the following form field is updated to the corresponding ["shares"] value.

What I have so far is below. I know my function is incorrect but My problem is I don't really know how to use document.getElementById to access the specific item from my list of dicts and get the "shares" value.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateMax() {
  var select = document.getElementById('symbol').innerText; // symbol selected
  const article = document.querySelector('select.val');  // finding article with symbol
  var maxi = article.dataset.shares; // getting maximum value
  var field = document.getElementById('shares');

     field.max = maxi

}
    </script>
    <form action="/sell" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="symbol" id="symbol" onchange="updateMax()">
                <option disabled selected value="">Symbol</option>
                  {% for row in portfolio %}
                     <article>
                       id="{{ row["symbol"] }}"
                       shares="{{ row["shares"] }}"
                     </article>
                <option value="row.symbol">{{ row["symbol"] }}</option>
                 {% endfor %}

            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="shares" autocomplete="off" min="0" max="" name="shares" placeholder="Shares" type="number">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sell</button>
    </form>
```

I tried following the instructions of the comment below. I am not sure I can create  inside the loop like this or what another option would be in case I can't.

I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Good UX! This function

```
 function updateMax() {
     var select = document.getElementById('symbol');
     var field = document.getElementById('shares');
     field.max = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value; }
```

has great promise; just one problem. The `value` of an option according to [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) is:

> **value**
>
> The content of this attribute represents the value to be submitted with the form, should this option be selected. If this attribute is
> omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option
> element.

Essentially it will simply give the `symbol` back.

Perhaps explore the HTML user-defined attribute `data-*`. Again from [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be
> associated with a particular element but need not have any defined
> meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on
> standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as
> non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or
> Node.setUserData().

Add the shares as a user-defined attribute on each option and the java script will have access to everything it needs. Something like:

```
<option data-shares="{{ row["shares"] }}" value="row.symbol">{{ row["symbol"] }}</option>
```

It can then be accessed in the javascript with the `dataset` property, something like: `HTMLelement.dataset.shares`

The second script is problematic: the javascript doesn't have access to the python variables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried doing something like this and it didnt quite work. I am sure I made a mistake somewhere. Can I create <articles> inside the for loop?
Just noticed i cant put code here so ill edit my post.

Comment: this `var maxi = article.dataset.shares; // getting maximum value` will return nothing (or maybe error, check the console) because there is no attribute `data-shares`. `select` can only have `option` or `optiongroup` children; `article` creates invalid html, it can be checked with [Nu validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea). Added info in answer to clarify. And make friends with the browser tools debugger :)